# Synthesis timing summary in Xilinx tool (ISE)

Tags: xilinx, timing, synthesis, ise

I'm getting the following timing summary from the synthesis:

```
Timing Summary:
---------------
Speed Grade: -1

   Minimum period: 9.982ns (Maximum Frequency: 100.180MHz)

   Minimum input arrival time before clock: 4.597ns

   Maximum output required time after clock: 4.364ns

   Maximum combinational path delay: 2.788ns
```

I want to improve that, is there a way to find the critical path and maybe buffer it up a bit?

I don't know what is the bottleneck..

Comment: If you say what tool you are using (ISE or Vivado), I can help, you can generate the detailed timing report but it is different on the 2 tools.

Comment: the question title says ISE...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run the generate_timing report on your design to get the detailed report for your design. In ISE you do it by choosing  Tools->Timing-Analyzer->PostMap

[image: ISE Timing Analyzer]

It will generate a report with the information you asked for.

For more accurate timing analysis of your design, you should look into the timing AFTER the P&R is done.

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck will be shown in explicit and gory detail just a little further down the synthesis report, in the "critical path" section for each timing constraint.

But before you pay too much attention to that : the "minimum period" is suspiciously close to 100 MHz. I would check to see if you had specified a 100 MHz clock timing constraint, increase it to 120 or 150MHz or ... and re-synthesize first. If synth can meet your actual goal without help, that's a much more time-efficient way to work.